# Debug jboss app in Intellij idea

Tags: debugging, jboss, intellij-idea

I am using `intellij` idea and `jboss server`.

When I run it it works fine but when I debug it it gives me:

```
ERROR: transport error 202: connect failed: Connection refused
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
Disconnected from server
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the jboss vm is running with the parameters Idea shows in Debug dialog - specifically the port number seems incorrect to me.

Comment: I unchecked pass variables then worked, i dunno what is the matter. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on OS X Mountain Lion you could try popping -d64 into the VM options, that seemed to work for me. Not passing the variables, I think, will just prevent you from debugging.

For more information check [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-82687).

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the pass variables didn't work for me.  What I ended up doing running the jBOSS separately and using 'Remote jBOSS' configuration in intelliJ.

To make debugging work I ened up adding the following lines to the "standalone.sh"

```
DEBUG_JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:62307,suspend=n,server=y "
JAVA_OPTS="${DEBUG_JAVA_OPTS} $JAVA_OPTS"
```

The value of DEBUG_JAVA_OPTS has to be copy and pasted from IntelliJ dialog box.  These lines have to be inserted into the script right after the place where script sets up "JAVA_OPTS"

**Update:**

Looks like IDE generates a new port number for each project.   So you have to edit the standalone.sh file every time you switch project.  Hopefully somebody can suggest a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to comment out the 'if' statement in standalone.conf as below.
Note the first $JAVA_OPTS is added (it is the one passed in from IntelliJ). This way there is no need to remember to change the port number for every project.

```
#Specify options to pass to the Java VM.
#
#if [ "x$JAVA_OPTS" = "x" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -    Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=$JBOSS_MODULES_SYSTEM_PKGS -Djava.awt.headless=true"
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml"
#else
#echo "JAVA_OPTS already set in environment; overriding default settings with val ues: $JAVA_OPTS"
#fi
```